# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on service call

Tags: spring-mvc, neo4j, nosuchmethoderror

I have below codes as shown below

```
@Repository
public interface SaleRepository extends GraphRepository<Sale> {
   @Query("MATCH (n:Sale) WHERE n.userId = {userId} RETURN n")
    Iterable<Sale> getSaleByUserId(@Param("userId") String userId);
}
```

Sale.JAva

```
@NodeEntity
public class Sale extends Entity implements Serializable{

   private Date createdDate;

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

}
```

SaleData.java

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/connect/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public String  SaleData(@PathVariable final String userId) 
    {

                            Sale saleObject = null;
            Iterable<Sale> saleData = SaleRepository.getSaleByUserId(String.valueOf(userPairInfo.getUserId()));
            if(saleData .iterator().hasNext())
            {
                saleObject= saleData .iterator().next();
            }

                         return "{\"userId\":\""+saleObject.getCreatedDate()+"\"}";   // on service call this gives me above error

}
```

if i call the service i get  error,

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.project.graphdb.neoj.domain.Sale.getCreatedDate()Ljava/util/Date
```

Its mainly tell because of sale.java file what else i am missing here?

Please help on this i am new to java and Neo4j

Answer (score 0):

Ï think you are using java.util.Date and not java.sql.Date or you might need to recompile your source code.